# Remove hover effect, if next element is visible

Tags: jquery, css

I created a simple box, which should open/close while clicking on it to show the content. I also want to user a hover on the h2-element. This is working, but there shouldn't be a hover effect, when the box is open.

Can this be done with CSS or do I have to use JS?

```js
    $('.box > h2').on('click', function() {
      $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
    });
```

```css
.box h2 {
      padding: .5em;
    }
    .box h2:hover {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .box > div {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <div>Any content</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is this "hover effect"? If you are referring to `background-color: #ccc;`, there is no problem with it.

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/j4jehbop/? This conditions can be handled with Jquery. Not sure about css.

Comment: You can't traverse back in CSS. You can't say "well, div is shown, now let's modify the previous element", sadly.

Comment: You will have to use JS here.

Comment: `toggleClass()` make perfect sense to me here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do it just with CSS, but you can add just a little bit change to your jQuery code to achieve this using the `toggleClass()` jQuery method:

Just add the hover effect in CSS when the `<h2>` have a `.closed` class , and then every time you do `slideToggle()` you remove/add `.closed` class from the clicked element. You can see code modified here:

```js
$('.box > h2').on('click', function() {
      $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
      $(this).toggleClass('closed');
  
    });
```

```css
.box h2 {
      padding: .5em;
    }
    .box h2.closed:hover {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .box > div {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
      <h2 class="closed">Title</h2>
      <div>Any content</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a `:visible` selector. You can toggle a `hover` class.

```js
 $('.box > h2').on('click', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('hover').next('div').slideToggle();
 }).hover(function() {
   if (!$(this).siblings('div').is(':visible')) {
     $(this).addClass('hover');
   }
 }, function() {
   $(this).removeClass('hover');
 });
```

```css
.box h2 {
  padding: .5em;
}
.box h2.hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.box > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div>Any content</div>
</div>
```